# trailing `_' in number if File.exist?(/home/4000_UW_spreadsheets/input_folio.ods) error

Tags: ruby

I'm getting some errors I don't understand:

```
spreadsheet:37: trailing `_' in number
                                if File.exist?(/home/4000_UW_spreadsheets/input_folio.ods)
                                                          ^
spreadsheet:37: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
                                if File.exist?(/home/4000_UW_spreadsheets/input_folio.ods)
                                                          ^
spreadsheet:37: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

So what do these errors mean? And how do I fix them..?

From this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

module Kernel
    def cd_to
        puts "Type 'go' to begin, press 'h' for help"
        input = gets.chomp.downcase
        case input
        when 'go'
            `cd '/'`
            `cd '/home/4000_UW_spreadsheets'`
            ls_grep
        when 'h'
            usage_help
        else
            puts "You're suppose to type 'go' stupid.."     
        end
    end

    def ls_grep
        puts "Folio number:"
        input_folio = gets.chomp
        case input_folio
        when input_folio =~ /^\d{7}/
            `ls -la|grep folio '#{input_folio}'`
            file_list.each do |input_folio|
                if File.exist?(/home/4000_UW_spreadsheets/input_folio.ods)
                    puts "Folio number #{input_folio} found"
                    remove #TO-DO make folio number run against file names
                end
            end
            remove #TO-DO make folio number run against file names
        else
            puts "Invalid file or directory"
            ls_grep
        end
    end

    def remove
        puts "Are you sure you want to unlock this folio?(Y/N)"
        input = gets.chomp.upcase
        case input
        when 'Y'
            `rm  ~folio'#{input_folio}'.lock`
        when 'N'
            puts "Exiting..."
            exit
        else
            puts "Error, exiting..."
            exit
        end
    end

    def usage_help
        puts <<-EOT.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >This program will unlock spreadhseets quickly and efficiently
            >To use follow the prompts and type in the folio number
            >Which should match the file name
            >
            >In the situation where the folio number doesn't match
            >The file name, get the file name and use it to unlock
            >The spreadsheet
            >
        EOT
    end
end
cd_to
```

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to point out a couple of ruby things.  First, I think it is usually a bad idea to open up the Kernel module. Most objects in ruby (including the Object class) inherit from it. So by adding methods to Kernel, you are affectively adding them everywhere. `Object.new.cd_to` for example.  You could add this to a module to help separate your code from other ruby code.  Secondly, there are many ruby methods you can use in stead of the shell commands you are calling. For example, `Dir.chdir(Dir.home)` is equivalent to `cd $HOME`. You might want to check out FileUtils too.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thank you.

Comment: @Etan, we do not disagree. My point is that the asker should treat their own answer the same as any other answer. If I were to ask a question, I might not accept the first answer posted, and certainly would not do so right away, even if I judged it to be excellent, as I wouldn't want to discourage other answers and would not want to short-circuit others still working on answers. Granted, the situation is somewhat different here because the question is no longer fresh, but any answer posted now may prompt other, possibly better, answers. After all, there's no rush to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the second error: you just need to add quotation marks around the path, like this

```
File.exist?("/home/4000_UW_spreadsheets/input_folio.ods")
```